# How TO Add UILocalNotifications TO An array

Tags: iphone, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hello Guys can anyone Explain me How to add UILocalNotifications to an Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
NSArray *existingNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
```